# Dates in jinja2 , when coming from sqlalchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Again I have another problem with outputing SQL Alchemy dates in flask/jinja2

my class is defined as

```
class vw_invoice_header(db.Model):

__tablename__ = "vw_invoice_header"
tax_amount = db.Column(db.Numeric)
total_price = db.Column(db.Numeric)
invc_number = db.Column(db.String(40))
term_code = db.Column(db.String(20))
order_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
airway_bill = db.Column(db.String(40))
inh_auto_key = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
invoice_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
company_po_number = db.Column(db.String(30))
ship_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
ship_address1 = db.Column(db.String(35))
ship_address2 = db.Column(db.String(35))
ship_address3 = db.Column(db.String(35))
ship_address4 = db.Column(db.String(35))
ship_address5 = db.Column(db.String(35))
attention = db.Column(db.String(50))
phone_number = db.Column(db.String(20))
email_address =  db.Column(db.String(60))
bill_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
bill_address1 = db.Column(db.String(35))
bill_address2 =  db.Column(db.String(35))
bill_address3 = db.Column(db.String(35))
bill_address4 = db.Column(db.String(35))
bill_address5 = db.Column(db.String(35))
so_numbers = db.Column(db.String(4000))
company_ref_numbers =  db.Column(db.String(4000))
currency =  db.Column(db.String(40))
is_complete = db.Column(db.String(1))
```

I'm doing a

```
invc = vw_invoice_header.query.filter_by(inh_auto_key=20643519).first()
```

why does

```
 {{invc.invoice_date.strftime('%d %b %y') }}
```

give me the results expected, yet -

```
 {{ '%d %b %y'.format(invc.invoice_date) }}
```

will not work for the life of me - I don't quite get the inconsitency.  I also had problems with a Numeric datatype, and had to convert it to a float to get the "".format to work...

Thank you

Comment: How come you expected this will work ? Can you expected this will work in pure python shell ? then we will contact jinja2 and ask them write a code to support that format you mention...\

Comment: I was assuming the documentation was actually correct                                   date.__format__(format)
Same as date.strftime(). This makes it possible to specify a format string for a date object when using str.format(). For a complete list of formatting directives, see strftime() and strptime() Behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the documentation states, it does work.
I had forgotten to wrap the {}placeholder in the actual string, 
so its

```
 {{ '{:%d %b %y}'.format(invc.invoice_date) }}
```

Thank you Raja for inspiring comments :P